# Open CV non-basic shape detection

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm using an Open CV wrapper, Emgu CV, to find try and find a target that is a non basic shape (see picture below). I've tried using HoughCircle detection  to find these shapes but it doesn't quite fully detect it (see picture below). Is there a better way to detect these shapes?

[image: target]

Comment: is cv::matchShapes wrapped in emguCV? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchshapes

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you exactly interested in, but you could try looking for contours instead of shapes.

See an example here:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

It could be also useful for you to play a bit with contours hierarchy:
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Interesting. But what logic would I use to determine that it is indeed my non-standard shape?

Comment: There are  a few functions you can use to extract contour features.

Have a look here: http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html#gsc.tab=0. Using these functions you could find a logic to filter out false contours.